# Iterating over RDD element

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of this type: (String, (Iterable[(String, Int)], Double)). I would like to transform this so that I can have a new RDD of the following type: (String, (Iterable[(String, Int)], Double)) where each Int in the original iterable is multiplied by the Double. How would one go about this? Most of my attampts have resulted in Unit RDDs not having any real data.

Comment: I suggest that you at least update your answer with what you tried to do!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you want. It compiles, I don't have a dataset to run it on.

```
def method(src: RDD[(String, (Iterable[(String, Int)], Double))]) = {
    src.map {
      case (s, (iter, d)) =>
         (s, (iter.map { case (s, i) => (s, (i * d).toInt) }, d))
    }
  }
```

Or mapValues might be more efficient, as it doesn't affect partitioning:

```
 def method(src: RDD[(String, (Iterable[(String, Int)], Double))]) = {
    src.mapValues {
      case (iter, d) =>
         (iter.map { case (s, i) => (s, (i * d).toInt) }, d)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can RDD.mapValues which will apply a given function to all values with keys being constant.

```
    def transformRdd(in: RDD[(String, (Iterable[(String, Int)], Double))]) := RDD[(String, (Iterable[(String, Int)], Double))]{
  in.mapValues{ 
//Here a will be iterable and b is Double
  case (a, b) => (a.map { case (str, int) => (str, (int * b).toInt) }, b)
  }
```

Now it will work ... Check if this compiles.

Comment: Returns the wrong type, though (as `b*d` is a `Double`)

Comment: And it doesn't compile for me. Did you test this? `in` is a `Tuple2`, and doesn't have a `map` method

Comment: Now it doesn't use its argument at all! (and so still doesn't compile)